# Visual Studio 2008 Solution Explorer going crazy when trying to run

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am attempting to run a web project in vs2008, however it just hangs before launching the ASP.NET development server.

The vertical scroll bar in the solution explorer starts moving up as if lots of new items are appearing (like when the script documents node is filled) and then moves back to the bottom and then moves up again.

I can run the project if I right click on an aspx page and 'View in Browser'.

Anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few weird bugs comes free with each edition of VS. Dont worry about that. Instead directly running from Development Server, use local IIS hosting. Sometimes because of CSS issues,   gets embeded when you switch betch Design and Source windows. Still MS is fixing those bugs. But I can suggest, go your own way...